# Java threading notify() method

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider there are two threads which are waiting to execute synchronized block. Now one get chance one is waiting in this case do I really need to call notify() ? I think as synchronized block execution completes other thread will release the lock ?  what is the exact use of notify() method ?

Threading experts please explain ?

Comment: [You can be a threading expert too!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, you wouldn't need to use `notify()` in that case. You are correct, the thread that had to wait to acquire the lock would automatically proceed after the lock was released.

The `notify()` method works in conjunction with the `wait()` method. When one thread invokes `wait()`, it may release the lock and begin waiting. One of the conditions that can end the wait is when another thread invokes `notify()`.  Both `wait()` and `notify()` must be invoked on an instance on which the current thread is `synchronized`.

This can be used, for example, to create a channel between two threads, where one thread is consuming information produced by another. If the consumer runs out of information to process, it might `wait()` until the producer does a `notify()` that more data are available.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread enter synchronized block and calls wait the lock acquired while entering the synchronized block is released and the thread waits for other thread to notify it in which case it will reacquire the lock and proceed.Lock is again released when the thread comes out of the synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29),

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If
>   any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be
>   awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the
>   implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one
>   of the wait methods.

so if an object is waiting by calling a `wait` method. then you can awake them using notify.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

> The java.lang.Object.notify() wakes up a single thread that is waiting
>   on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object,
>   one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and
>   occurs at the discretion of the implementation. A thread waits on an
>   object's monitor by calling one of the wait methods.

For more information refer below links.

[notify()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_notify.htm)

[Documentation](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/network/prirucky/javatut/java/threads/waitAndNotify.html)

[Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. if I don't call wait() method do I need to call notify method ?

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212721/how-to-handle-questions-answerable-by-a-link-to-the-documentation). If you're going to refer to documentation, at least explain how it applies.

Answer (score 0):

Like if you are using Multiple threads the method is synchronized which means it will share among all the threads but any thread will use it after the execution another thread. 
and if there is any change is made by any thread then it will visible for all by using notify method below code is example for that:

```
class Detail {
    public String name = "", sername = "";
    Scanner sc;

    public synchronized String getData() {

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name+""+sername;
    }

    public synchronized void show() {
        try {
            name = "hello";
            sername = "hii";
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        notify();


    }

}

class Data1 extends Thread {
    Detail detail;
    public Data1(Detail detail1)
    {
    //  super("1");
        this.detail = detail1;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("name is :"+detail.getData());

    }
}

class Data2 extends Thread {
    Detail detail2;
    public Data2(Detail detail1)
    {
        //super("2");
        this.detail2 = detail1;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        detail2.show();

    }
}

public class SyncDemo {

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Detail det = new Detail();
        Data1 d1=  new Data1(det);
        Data2 d2=  new Data2(det);

    }

}
```